# Update Windows 7 laptop domain profile over VPN

Tags: windows-7, domain, profile, cisco-vpn-client

I have a company laptop that is a member of our domain, and I access the network using the Cisco VPN client 5.0.07.0290. I just changed my domain password at work using my desktop computer, and now the laptop profile is out of sync. It still uses the previous password. In lieu of bringing the laptop into work, how can I update the profile on my laptop over the VPN? The laptop runs Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy:

- Log in on the laptop without network and using the **old** password.
- Then connect the network and start your VPN connection to work.
- Now lock your laptop. <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd> Lock).
- Then unlock it using the **new** password.

At the time of unlocking the computer is connected to the domain (via the VPN tunnel) and it will verify the password with the domain. As a side effect this will update the password on the laptop.

Comment: Easy, yes. Discoverable? Not so much :-(

Comment: Most VPNs are still from a work laptop to the company network. Which makes these kind of questions to their systemadmin. (Speaking as one of those: I also put that kind of information on our intranet sites under frequently asked questions).

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, except that whenever i shutdown the laptop again, I need to do the same thing all over again, Is there a way to update the cached Profile details on the Laptop. So that i can use the new password?

Comment: Also windows 7?  (not tested by me on anything more modern and the OP did use W7).